# In the GraphQL reference implementation resolvers are expected to return an Iterable, how to return an asynchronous Iterable?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using [`Sequelize`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) to access my relational database and deliver the results in a [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) resolver. Queries within the `Sequelize` framework are executed asynchronously ([bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)). In order to *buffer large result sets* and avoid *high memory demands* on the server when, e.g. millions of records are requested, I thought of returning an Iterator in my resolver. Consider this simplified gist:

```
// root resolver
function allPersons(...) {
  [...]
  return {
    nextId: 1,
    maxId: 10000000, 
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => { return this },
    next: function() {
      let nextRes = { done: true, value: null }
      if (this.nextId <= this.maxId) {
        nextRes.value = sequelize.models.person.findById(this.currId)
        nextRes.done = false
        this.nextId = this.nextId + 1
      }
      return nextRes
    }
}
```

The above works, because a Sequelize constructed Promise is returned as `next()`'s `value`. When the this value-Promise is resolved it fetches a single record from the underlying relational database. Thus, I *synchronously* construct *asynchronous* data fetching. This only works, because each single fetch is independent of all others. Particularly no single fetch needs to be `await`ed, before executing the next. However, fetching row by row of a relational database is technically inefficient and in fact an anti-pattern. Thus I'd like to implement a buffer, that fetches batches of say 10k rows, serves them until the batch is empty, and then fetches the next one. However, because of the then introduced dependency of asynchronous events, to implement this, one would need an asynchronous Iterator ([`Symbol.asyncIterator`](https://medium.com/@nairihar/async-iteration-in-nodejs-v10-3c17dc00ed9f)).

What would I have to do to make [`GraphQL's reference implementation`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) (graphql-js and/or express-graphql) accept an asynchronous Iterator?
Please be advised, that I'd like to avoid usage of [Apollo GraphQL](https://www.apollographql.com/).

Or would an Object-Stream be a possible solution?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL.js uses `iterall` under the hood. To support asynchronous iterables, the the underlying code would have to utilize the `forAwaitEach` method from that library instead of the `forEach` method its using now. That may be possible, but I'm not sure if it wouldn't break other functionality.

If all you want to do is fetch all `people` in some arbitrarily-sized chunks, you don't need to do anything particularly fancy:

```
async function getAllPeople () {
  const chunkSize = 10000
  const startId = 1
  const endId = await sequelize.models.person.max('id')
  const people = []

  let lower = startId
  let upper = startId + chunkSize

  while (upper < (endId + 1)) {
    const chunk = await sequelize.models.person.findAll({
      where: {
        id: {
          [Op.and]: {
            [Op.gte]: lower,
            [Op.lt]: upper,
          }
        }
      },
    })
    people.push(chunk)
    lower = lower + chunkSize
    upper = upper + chunkSize
  }

  return people
}
```

**EDIT:** To get around the memory issue, you would have to effectively break up the payload into multiple responses and have a way to put them back together on the client side. There's a `@stream` directive that's on Apollo's roadmap that does just that and I think some folks have experimented with it, but I imagine it may be a while before we see a mature implementation of it. `@defer` has a similar mechanism, and is currently supported by Apollo but works at the resolver-level so it wouldn't really help in this case.

You could possibly hack it using [subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/features/subscriptions.html), which incidentally do use async iterators. You would still potentially need to trigger sending the data using a query or mutation, but could then send it to the client via subscription.

I think unfortunately the simplest solution given the current tooling would be to just implement pagination on the query and have the client piece together the total result.

Comment: Dear @Daniel Rearden, 
thank you for your quick response and insights. However it seems my memory load problem remains unsolved, if I'm not mistaken. Would your code not fill the memory with all existing `person` records before returning them to the GraphQL framework, which ultimately writes them into the Http Response? The usage of an async Iterator, that only loads chunks when its current batch has been served by its `async` `next`, or an object-stream that does the same, would indeed solve my problem, right? 
How would I make `graphql-js` make accept object-streams or async iterators?

Comment: I imagine under the existing architecture, the entire response needs to be stored in memory before it can be sent. In other words, as far as I'm aware, it's not possible to do what you're asking. At best, it could be broken up into separate responses, which would then be pieced together by the client. Please see my updated answer above for more details.

Comment: Dear Daniel, thanks a lot for your feedback. For now we will use classical pagination then. I hope the reference implementation of GraphQL will implement support for asynchronous Iterators in the future. I'm guessing we are not the only ones who would be happy about that feature. As to Subscriptions, am I correct in assuming they are not yet fully implemented in the reference `graphql-js` package? I cannot find any documentation about it, except [this blog](https://graphql.org/blog/subscriptions-in-graphql-and-relay/) from 2015.

Comment: GraphQL.js does in fact implement subscriptions (the documentation is a bit lacking in general). However, just like it doesn't provide a specific solution for integrating with an HTTP server and requires a separate package to do so (`apollo-server`, `express-graphql`, etc.), it also requires a separate package to provide the transport for the subscriptions (and a client that supports them as well!). Take a gander at `subscriptions-transport-ws`

Answer (score 0):

#### Half a solution: Use streams and convert them to a *synchronous* iterator

Because GraphQL resolvers are expected to return synchronous iterators, streams can be used to feed their data into such an iterator. Consider the following solution of the original example as posted in the question. Please note, that the popular ORM [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) does not support streams and thus another node package [`knex`](https://knexjs.org) is used here.

```
// Setup:
const knex = require('knex')
var dbCon = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {} // Define host, user, password, db (see knex docu)
})

// Get records as stream
var peopleStream = dbCon.select('*').from('people').stream()

// Serve stream within an synchronous iterator
var iter = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
    return this
  },
  next: function() {
    let v = peopleStream.read() || null
    console.log(JSON.stringify(v)) // Check, if it works.
    return {
      done: v === null,
      value: v
    }
  }
}
```

However, this indeed is just *half a solution*, because only data sources can be utilized in the shown manner that generate streams - which in turn can easily be converted to synchronous iterators as shown here. In my humble opinion GraphQL's reference implementation urgently needs to support asynchronous iterators as result values of resolvers. See [this feature request](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1537) for more details.